# How do I remove the previous string from reader?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do I remove the previous string from reader? The first string is correct ("41 24.2028") but every string that comes after that just stacks ("41 24.202841 24.2028").

I did try to clear the LatTaken/LongTaken and the messageBox shows the correct string ("41 24.2028").

But the double.Parse(splitX[1]); shows an error (System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.')

What do I do? Is there other way to do this?

```
        connection.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT LatTaken, LongTaken, Temp, humi, Baro, TempAir from ParsedReadings";

        command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            LatTaken += reader.GetValue(0);
            LongTaken += reader.GetValue(1);

            Temp += reader.GetDouble(2);
            humi += reader.GetDouble(3);

            Baro += reader.GetDouble(4);
            TempAir += reader.GetDouble(5);

            MessageBox.Show(LatTaken);
            var splitX = LatTaken.Split();
            MessageBox.Show(splitX[1]);
            var degreeX = double.Parse(splitX[0]);
            var minutesX = double.Parse(splitX[1]);

            var splitX2 = LongTaken.Split();
            var degreeX2 = double.Parse(splitX2[0]);
            var minutesX2 = double.Parse(splitX2[1]);

            var resultX = degreeX + minutesX / 60;
            var resultX2 = degreeX2 + minutesX2 / 60;

            Temp = 0f;
            humi = 0f;
            Baro = 0f;
            TempAir = 0f;
            LatTaken = string.Empty;
            LongTaken = string.Empty;
        }

        reader.Close();
        command.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing `+=` and not just `=` this will append the new value to the existing one each time you loop. Also you should look up parameterised SQL queries.

Comment: I did try to make it LatTaken = reader.GetString(0) but it still has error (System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.').